# How to convert dd/MM/YYYY formatted string date to YYYY-MM-dd datetime?

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I wanna convert `dd/MM/YYYY` formatted string date to `YYYY-MM-dd` datetime. But it returns to me

> "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

How can i convert from "04/26/2016" string to  yyyy-MM-dd datetime format?

```
 DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("04/26/2016", "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
 Console.WriteLine(dt);
```

Comment: `ParseExact("04/26/2016", "yyyy-MM-dd"` <-- spot the error?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You parse the string with date in wrong way.
You should:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("04/26/2016", "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

Comment: That is just totally wrong. `-` and `/` don't match well.

Comment: FYI, I _really_ love to use `InvariantCulture` in `ToString` method because OP's `CurrentCulture` _might_ not use `GregorianCalendar` as a `Calendar` property. In such a case, this `ToString` method generates different result than `2016-04-16`.

Answer (score 6):

Technically, you can do just some *string manipulations*:

```
String source = "04/26/2016";
String result = String.Join("-", source.Split('/').Reverse());
```

But, `DateTime.ParseExact` is a better solution:

```
String result = DateTime
  .ParseExact(source, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
  .ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, your format and string does not exactly match. From [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact);

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent. **The format of the string representation must
>   match a specified format exactly or an exception is thrown**.

You should use `MM/dd/yyyy` format instead.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("04/26/2016", "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

And if you wanna get it's string representation with `yyyy-MM-dd` format, just use `ToString` method like;

```
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Be aware, there is no `YYYY` as a custom date format. Since those specifiers are case sensitive, you should use [`yyyy` format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#yyyySpecifier) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("04/26/2016", "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
 Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

Comment: you use wrong format to parse, there is no month with number 26

Comment: @PatrickHofman It was like `dd/MM/yyyy` in first revision but since OP changed it _so quickly_, we didn't see it as a revision and it's okey now.

Comment: It was wrong, maybe answer was edited

Comment: @SonerGönül Thanks. I didn't see that obviously.

Comment: yes I have edited the answer, in question asked for dd/MM/yyyy but put 04/26/2016 so mistake was there,  thanks @Roma

Comment: By the way, I _really_ love to use `InvariantCulture` in `ToString` method because OP's `CurrentCulture` _might_ not use `GregorianCalendar` as a `Calendar` property. In such a case, this `ToString` method generates different result than `2016-04-16`.

Comment: return inObj == DBNull.Value ? "" : (Convert.ToDateTime(inObj)).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy").ToString();